# Summation with for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I input 10 to the below sequence, the it prints sum = 56
I list what sum includes, they are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. I wonder what's wrong with the calculation of sum.

=======================================

```
n = int(input('input number?'))

sum = 1


for i in range(1,n+1,1):

     sum += i


print(sum)
```

Comment: You are starting the loop from one and also have initialized the sum with 1. It is a logical error rather than a programmatical one. Try setting up `sum = 0`. 
Note: default `steps` are 1 in Python loop, so the third param in the range is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, sum is a builtin, change it to something like 'sumval' instead. For instance: "sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])" should give you "55".

Comment: It works now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you first define sum = 1.
The true result is 55 but you increment it by yourself.

true code is below

```py
n = int(input('input number?'))
result = sum(range(1, n+1))
```

You should not use sum as a variable name because sum is a built-in function.
And in this case, you can calculate summantion by sum so easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the variable 'sum' is initialized to 1. It should be 0. You will get the correct result. :)